# Future of the "SAP Java Connector"

Tags: connector, sap-erp, jco

Is the **SAP Java Connector** still a good way to connect a Java Application with SAP ? Will there be a support and maintenance of the connector in the future (especially in ECC 6.0) or is the one and only good way the usage of the "Enterprise Services" in **ECC 6.0** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering that the Java Connector was only recently re-developed to version 3 and is now used to bridge the gap between the NetWeaver Java Stack and its ABAP counterpart, it's safe to assume the JCo will be around for quite some time. I'd always prefer using the JCo to Web Services if I have the choice - less overhead, easier on the ABAP side. You might want to take a look at tools like [HiberSAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibersap/), [RCER](http://rcer.sourceforge.net/) or [sap4j](http://sap4j.com/) to make life a little easier on the Java side - that is, reducing the amount of boilerplate code and focusing on the really important things.

Comment: Thank you for listing the tools - that is useful :) We use the [sap4j](http://sap4j.com), which is handy to pull data into files or a local DB for some ETL processes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course. SAP introduces new CE products all the time but they dont make the java connector obsolete at all because you should still be able to integrate third party software into your sap landscape. Since enterprise services can be exposed as SOAP services as well in ECC 6.0 you could use any java soap library. But I think RFC is the way to go in respect to performance (I've not tried it myself, thats just what I hear)

Answer (score 0):

The future looks still good for the Java Connector.
SAP has just released a new version.

The new SAP Java Connector 3.1 SDK can be downloaded from https://support.sap.com/jco .